# Dafny, replace index by value in sequences

Tags: z3, verification, dafny

in the Dafny tutorial at [rise4fun](https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/tutorial/Sequences), `s[i := v]` is defined for replacing the index `i` by `v` in sequence `s`. 
but using this always fails with `expected method call, found expression`.

for instance in the code below for swapping two indexes

```
var a:int :=input[j];
var b:int :=input[j-1];
input[j := b]; //expected method call, found expression
input[j-1 := a]; //expected method call, found expression
```

what is the correct way of using `s[i := v]` in a case like swapping two indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write

```
var a:int :=input[j];
var b:int :=input[j-1];
input := input[j:=b] ;
input := input[j-i : a];
```

More succinctly, but perhaps harder to read

```
input := input[ j := input[j-1] ][ j-1 := input[j] ] ;
```

Comment: Thanks but it gives error: "LHS of assignment must denote a mutable variable". Actually I do not want to make another local variable, cause it makes lots of trouble for the rest of program. is there a way to do in place swapping?

Comment: Well that's because `index` is not a mutable variable. The correct solution is to make another variable.  (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50440756/dafny-function-invalid-logical-expression-on-while-loop/50451388?noredirect=1#comment87990455_50451388 for example.) For in-place swapping, use an array rather than a sequence.