# Dafny function, invalid logical expression on while loop

Tags: z3, verification, insertion-sort, dafny

I am new in Dafny and getting some errors that I can not figure it out.

- in my Dafny program for insertionSort ([the code is here](https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/uj6)), I do not understand why I get an `invalid logical expression` on While loop over variable `i`. `while (i < |input|)`
- in the same code at the swapping part (`input[j := b]; input[j-1 := a];`) also I get `expected method call, found expression`. According to the tutorial `input[j:=b]` is replacing index j of seq input with the value of b

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first error is because you are declared a `function` rather than a `method`. In Dafny the body of a `function` is expected to be an expression, not a sequence of statements.  So when the parser sees the keyword "while", it realizes something is wrong (since "while" can't be part of a statement) and gives an error message.  I'm not sure why the error message refers to a "logical" expression.

Anyway, you can fix this problem by declaring a `method` rather than a `function`.

You need a method because you are using an imperative algorithm and not a functional algorithm. It's true that you want a subroutine that computes its output as a function of its input with no side effects. But, in Dafny, you still use a `method` for this when the way you want to do it involves imperative constructs like assignments and while loops.

---

The second problem is that `input[j := b]` is an expression whereas the parser exepected a statement. You can fix this by rewriting `input[j := b]; input[j-1 := a];` as `input := input[j:=b]; input := input[j-1];`.

---

Unfortunately, that will lead to another problem, which is that, in Dafny, input parameters can't be assigned to.  So you are better off making another variable.  See below, for how I did that.

```
method insertionSort(input:seq<int>)
// The next line declares a variable you can assign to.
// It also declares that the final value of this variable is the result
// of the method.
returns( output : seq<int> )
    // No reads clause is needed.
    requires |input|>0
    // In the following I changed "input" to "output" a few places
    ensures perm(output,old(input))
    ensures sortedBetween(output, 0, |output|) // 0 to input.Length = whole input

{
    output := input ;
    // From here on I changed your "input" to "output" most places
    var i := 1;
    while (i < |output|) 
        invariant perm(output,old(input))
        invariant 1 <= i <= |output|
        invariant sortedBetween(output, 0, i)       
        decreases |output|-i
    {
        ...
            output := output[j := b];
            output := output[j-1 := a];
            j := j-1;
        ...
    }
}
```

By the way, since input parameters can't be changed, wherever you have `old(input)`, you could just use `input`.  They mean the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. here is a problem the "ensures"  before assigning the input to output (output:=input) does not hold. should I move them all as invariant into inside the method body?

Comment: so in this case the post condition does not hold and the invariant of perm(output,old(output)) says: possible violation of function precondition

Comment: Your question was about syntax errors, so I only gave enough of an answer to get you to a point where the code will pass syntax checking and other checks that need to be passed before code can be sent to the verifier.  Now that the code is getting to the verifier you are getting verification errors.  Some quick answers to these new questions follow.

Comment: "the 'ensures' assigning the input to output (output:=input) does not hold".  Even though the ensures comes before the body, it is expected to be true after the body is finished.  Anyway leave the ensures where it is.  The `requires` and `ensures` clauses are all the callers of the method can depend on.

Comment: "the invariant of perm(output,old(output)) says: possible violation of function precondition". You might need another invariant to say that the length of `output` is the same as the length of `input`. Put that one earlier than the one with the precondition problem.

Comment: "in this case the post condition does not hold ".  I think this is a consequence of the invariant not verifying. In anycase make sure the invariants all verify before worrying about the postconditions.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. Also I just learned about 'fresh' keyword that helped alot and yes changed invariants. Thanks again